# VSCode Javascript, Greyed Breakpoint ignored because generated code not found

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, visual-studio-code

I'm working with VSCode and the VSCode chrome debugger

The message when hovering over the greyed out breakpoint is: "Breakpoint ignored because generated code not found (source map problem?)"

My launch.json is as follows

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
        },
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to Chrome",
            "port": 9222,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried adding things like smartstep, setting sourceMaps to true, and sourceMapPathOverrides but none has work.

This problem only happens in background.js, as breakpoints in content.js and other js files are working.

Edit:
I'm adding the manifest and a part of the background.js file

manifest file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "name",
  "description": "This extension helps",
  "version": "0.1",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_title": "Extension",
    "default_popup": "default_popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "https://*/*",
    "http://*/*",
    "idle",
    "storage"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": [
          "<all_urls>"
        ],
        "js": ["jquery-2.1.3.min.js", "content.js","logout.js"]
      }
    ],
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
}
```

part of background that doesn't allow breaks:

```
chrome.idle.onStateChanged.addListener( localState => {
    if(localState === stateLiterals.locked){
        console.log("test");
    }
}
);
```

in general, none of background.js allows me to add breaks properly so I believe the issue is probably with the launch file and VSCode.

Specifically, the desired behavior is to get breakpoints in VSCode to work when debugging, and as specified above, currently the problem is that the breakpoint is greyed out and gives a message: "Breakpoint ignored because generated code not found (source map problem?)"

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: @Makyen I edited the original post with the information added. Please let me know if theres anything else needed